# VS2015 application crashes when calling C++ function with delegates

Tags: c++, delegates

I am using ABBYY's FineReader engine, and when trying to initialize, my application crashes (while debugging). If I run the .exe it works fine.

Declarations:

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll")>
Private Shared Function LoadLibrary(dllToLoad As String) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("kernel32.dll")>
Private Shared Function GetProcAddress(hModule As IntPtr, procedureName As String) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("kernel32.dll")>
Private Shared Function FreeLibrary(hModule As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

' FREngine.dll functions
<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Private Delegate Function GetEngineObject(devSN As String, reserved1 As String, reserved2 As String, ByRef engine As FREngine.IEngine) As Integer
<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Private Delegate Function DeinitializeEngine() As Integer
<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Private Delegate Function DllCanUnloadNow() As Integer
```

and to initialize:

```
 ' Load the FREngine.dll library
    dllHandle = LoadLibrary(enginePath)

    Try
        If dllHandle = IntPtr.Zero Then
            Throw New Exception("Can't load " + enginePath)
        End If

        Dim getEngineObjectPtr As IntPtr = GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "GetEngineObject")
        If getEngineObjectPtr = IntPtr.Zero Then
            Throw New Exception("Can't find GetEngineObject function")
        End If
        Dim deinitializeEnginePtr As IntPtr = GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "DeinitializeEngine")
        If deinitializeEnginePtr = IntPtr.Zero Then
            Throw New Exception("Can't find DeinitializeEngine function")
        End If
        Dim dllCanUnloadNowPtr As IntPtr = GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "DllCanUnloadNow")
        If dllCanUnloadNowPtr = IntPtr.Zero Then
            Throw New Exception("Can't find DllCanUnloadNow function")
        End If

        ' Convert pointers to delegates
        _getEngineObject = DirectCast(Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(getEngineObjectPtr, GetType(GetEngineObject)), GetEngineObject)
        _deinitializeEngine = DirectCast(Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(deinitializeEnginePtr, GetType(DeinitializeEngine)), DeinitializeEngine)
        _dllCanUnloadNow = DirectCast(Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(dllCanUnloadNowPtr, GetType(DllCanUnloadNow)), DllCanUnloadNow)

        ' Call the GetEngineObject function
        Dim hresult As Integer = _getEngineObject(developerSN, Nothing, Nothing, m_engine)
```

The last line is the one that causes the crash (no errors or output). The same code works fine in VS2010, but not in VS2015. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it crashes is because you're using a non-developer license to debug ABBYY in Visual Studio, unfortunately it crashes without providing a meaningful exception and there's no information about this on their support site.

Ensure you're using a developer license whilst debugging and a run-time license if running it via the exe.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the project properties of your project in VS2010 and apply the same settings in VS2015, Check include library paths and make sure the DLL is located in the right location

Comment: It is the exact same solution, just opened it with VS2015 on another machine, so project settings are the same. All requirements and applications have been installed. (dlls are in the same location)